# How to split data with awk

Tags: shell, awk

I would like to use awk to work on some files. I have a file like this:

input:

```
a     2   16  
b    17   25   
c    26   32   
d    33   51
```

and what I want is to split all rows to enumerate the range  between column 2 and column 3, incrementing the numbers by 2. For example:

```
a  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16  
b  17 19 21 23 25  
c  26 28 30 32  
d  33 35 37 39 41 43 45 47 49 51
```

Comment: It's just a simple `for` loop that increments by 2.

Comment: Please show your attempt, we're not here to do your work for you. If you can't get it working, we'll help you fix it.

Comment: what should happen if $2 is odd and $3 is even, for example, so the range isn't a multiple of 2?

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk ' { printf("%-3s", $1)
>         for (i=$2; i<=$3; i+=2)
>             printf ("%-3d", i)
>         printf("\n") } ' <<EOF
> a   2  16
> b   17 25
> c   26 32
> d   33 51
> EOF
a  2  4  6  8  10 12 14 16
b  17 19 21 23 25
c  26 28 30 32
d  33 35 37 39 41 43 45 47 49 51
```

Comment: You can use `print ""` in place of `printf("\n")` -- a little tidier.